# Java: How do you convert a UTC timestamp to local time?

Tags: java, date, calendar, timezone

I have a timestamp that's in UTC and I want to convert it to local time without using an API call like `TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST")`.  How exactly are you supposed to do this?  I've been using the following code without much success:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat mSegmentStartTimeFormatter = new        SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        calendar.setTime(mSegmentStartTimeFormatter.parse(startTime));
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Sample input value: `[2012-08-15T22:56:02.038Z]`

should return the equivalent of `[2012-08-15T15:56:02.038Z]`

Comment: **Update:** The code here uses terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. For a modern solution, see the [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46011166/642706)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`Date` has no timezone and internally stores in UTC. Only when a date is formatted is the timezone correction applies. When using a `DateFormat`, it defaults to the timezone of the JVM it's running in. Use `setTimeZone` to change it as necessary.

```
DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Date date = utcFormat.parse("2012-08-15T22:56:02.038Z");

DateFormat pstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
pstFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));

System.out.println(pstFormat.format(date));
```

This prints `2012-08-15T15:56:02.038`

Note that I left out the `'Z'` in the PST format as it indicates UTC. If you just went with `Z` then the output would be `2012-08-15T15:56:02.038-0700`

Comment: Cool it actually worked.  I was able to get the Android device's default timezone by calling TimeZone.getDefault().

Comment: it is not changing, it is same as UTC time, what can i do ?

Comment: this post not answer the question

Answer (score 27):

Use the modern Java date & time API, and this is straightforward:

```
    String inputValue = "2012-08-15T22:56:02.038Z";
    Instant timestamp = Instant.parse(inputValue);
    ZonedDateTime losAngelesTime = timestamp.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
    System.out.println(losAngelesTime);
```

This prints

```
2012-08-15T15:56:02.038-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

Points to note:

- There’s a little bug in your expectations. The `Z` in your timestamp means UTC, also known as Zulu time. So in your local time value, the `Z` should not be there. Rather you would want a return value like for example `2012-08-15T15:56:02.038-07:00`, since the offset is now -7 hours rather than Z.
- Avoid the three letter time zone abbreviations. They are not standardized and therefore most often ambiguous. PST, for example, may mean Philppine Standard Time, Pacific Standard Time or Pitcairn Standard Time (though S in an abbreviation is often for summer time (meaning DST)). If you intended Pacific Standard Time, that isn’t even a time zone, since in summer (where your sample timestamp falls) Pacific Daylight Time is used instead. Instead of the abbreviations use time zone IDs in the format *region/city* as in my code.
- Timestamps are generally best handled as `Instant` objects. Convert to `ZonedDateTime` only when you have a need, like for presentation.

**Question: Can I use the modern API with my Java version?**

If using at least Java **6**, you can.

- In Java 8 and later the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of the new classes (that’s ThreeTen for JSR-310, where the modern API was first defined).
- On Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP, and I think that there’s a wonderful explanation in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

```
    Instant timestamp = Instant.parse("2023-07-25T11:04:31.650Z");  
    System.out.println(timestamp.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toOffsetDateTime());
```

Prints for my location:

2023-07-25T13:04:31.650+02:00

Comment: I am glad to see you wanting to contribute to Stack Overflow. However, I see two problems with your Answer: (A) This approach was already covered in the existing [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46011166/642706). (B)  I do not see the point of your conversion from `ZonedDateTime` to `OffsetDateTime`, as that discards valuable information (the time zone) while gaining nothing in return.

Answer (score -1):

**Here is a Simple Modified solution**

```
    public String convertToCurrentTimeZone(String Date) {
            String converted_date = "";
            try {

                DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

                Date date = utcFormat.parse(Date);

                DateFormat currentTFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                currentTFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(getCurrentTimeZone()));

                converted_date =  currentTFormat.format(date);
            }catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}

            return converted_date;
    }


    //get the current time zone

    public String getCurrentTimeZone(){
            TimeZone tz = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
            System.out.println(tz.getDisplayName());
            return tz.getID();
    }
```