# java code to convert UTC time to local datetime with an offset compare

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, utc

We receive datetime elements relative to the UTC time like `2004-04-12T13:20:00Z`.

And we would like to output the datetime in the local datetime, that is expressed with an offset relative to the UTC time like `2004-04-12T12:20:00-01:00.`

Comment: Go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487125/java-how-do-you-convert-a-utc-timestamp-to-local-time. Hope you get the right answer..

Comment: The Java 8 date and time classes are perfect for this (much better than oldfashioned `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`). Can you use Java 8?

Answer (score 7):

With the Java 8 date and time classes this is straightforward. Only catch is, we need to go through `ZoneDateTime` if we want to pick om the computer’s default time zone, and then on to `OffsetDateTime` to get the output format you requested (another option would be formatting the date and time using a specific `DateTimeFormatter`; now I am relying on `OffsetDateTime.toString()`).

```
    String utcTime = "2004-04-12T13:20:00Z";
    OffsetDateTime dateTimeWithOffset = Instant.parse(utcTime).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(dateTimeWithOffset);
```

On my computer the above prints

```
2004-04-12T14:20+01:00
```

In the answer and the code I have on purpose avoided the term “local date-time” that you used in the question. This is to avoid confusion with the class `LocalDateTime`, which is used for a date and time *without* any time zone or offset information.

Comment: Good answer. I suggest changing the name of you `localtime` var to something like `offsetDateTime` and point out the orignal poster’S misunderstanding of the term "local".

Answer (score 1):

Use `ZonedDateTime` from the java 8 API.

```
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse("2004-04-12T13:20:00Z"), ZoneId.of("CET"))
```

it will give you `2004-04-12T15:20+02:00[CET]`

Answer (score -1):

Hope the below solution works.

```
String date_s = "2004-04-12T13:20:00Z"; 
    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"); 
    Date date = dt.parse(date_s); 

     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // creates calendar
        cal.setTime(date); // sets calendar time/date
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1); // adds one hour (do any offset that you want here)
        String out = dt.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(out.substring(1));
```

Comment: The terribly troublesome `Date` and `Calendar` classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score -1):

Using the Java 8 JDK, you can use the `java.time.Instant` class to refer to UTC time. and the folloowing classes for the offset times :

java.time.LocalDate
java.time.LocalTime
java.time.LocalDateTime

Example :

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.ofOffset("MyZoneId", ZoneOffset.ofHours(3)));
```