# Convert datetime string to local time using java

Tags: java, android, mobile, time

I have a datetime string with the format of

```
String date = "2021-05-26 14:23"  // GMT Time
```

**Now my question is how can I convert in to local time** its the GMT time..?
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Have you tried anything? If not, find out about `java.time`, otherwise please show us your attemtp(s) in code.

Comment: Follow the link https://www.java67.com/2016/04/how-to-convert-string-to-localdatetime-in-java8-example.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert UTC DateTime to another Time Zone using Java 8 library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54108388/how-to-convert-utc-datetime-to-another-time-zone-using-java-8-library)

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.time` classes:

- `DateTimeFormatter` to parse (and format)
- `LocalDateTime` to represent the given input
- `ZonedDateTime` to include the GMT time zone,
  and convert to another zone
- if needed, `DateTimeFormatter` to format as string

Example:

```
var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
var input = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter).atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT"));
```

this can now be changed to another zone using `withZoneSameInstant(...)` and then, if desired, changed `toLocalTime()` or `toLocalDateTime()`; or `format(...)` to text.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert `String` date/time to more universal timestamp with

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
long timestampGmt = sdf.parse(date).getTime(); // as timestamp

int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() + 
    TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings(); // currently set time zone offset
long timestampCurrent = timestampGmt  - offset;

String newDate = sdf.format(timestampCurrent); // again to string with same structure
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android look into [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or see [How to use ThreeTenABP …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).